# Spree category pages in custom rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have created a default rails app. I am beginner to spree.

I am not able to find the code for the pages which are coming by default in the spree app.

This is how I have created the app

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.2
gem install bundler
gem install spree_cmd
rails _4.2.2_ new mystore
cd mystore
spree install --auto-accept
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/t/categories/bags` I get all the categories for this category.

But in my view I do not see any code. So from where are these coming from?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is coming from spree gems, you can see the front end code by opening the gem file in your editor by following. (you need to set you environment variables EDITOR or BUNDLER_EDITOR)

```
bundle open spree_frontend
```

or else you can do in terminal

```
bundle show spree_frontend
open 'path above something like  /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spree_frontend-3.0.8'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. So I can edit the files in this gem directly and the changes will reflect in my app?!

Comment: no you should not edit the files in the gem directly.  Please see here to see how the view customisation is done in spree.. https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/view.html

Answer (score 1):

These pages come from within the Spree gem, which adds routes and views. Have a poke around and see what you find here: https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/core/app

It runs as a Rails engine, so read up on how that works here if you want to know how the gem adds routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Answer (score 1):

See rails request/response log to find the rendered partials path in a request.

Also you may find http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/view.html helpful.