# Rails - How To Customize Spree Commerce Framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I just started learning about the `Spree Commerce Rails Framework` for building a foundation for e-commerce website for my class's final project, even though I have only taken one introductory `Ruby on Rails` course at school. I went through their "Getting Started" tutorial from the following link:

https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html

However, I noticed that after creating a `Spree Commerce` starter project, I do not have access to the source code! It seems that I'm given no control over the models, controllers, view html files, etc. Why not?

How do I get access to these source files? For example, I want to completely take out the "checkout and payment transaction" functionality to ONLY display products and let the user have a wish list, but I'm not seeing where or how I can customize it to that point.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282646/spree-category-pages-in-custom-rails-app/36283387#36283387

Comment: so if I want complete control over the source code, I should just download the core app from the GitHub repo?

Comment: do you mean you want to add customisations ? please see here for view customisation. https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/view.html

Comment: This is for a group project for school. I also have to add a "compare products" view and a chat feature for customers to chat with vendors :( so I'm going to have to add some more functionality as well as customize some views. Spree seems to have a pretty tediously complex way of customization, especially since I only took an introductory rails course, which is why editing the gem's files sounded like a good idea

Comment: if you want to customise spree that is the way to do it as in spree documentation. If you update the gem file it self. you will probably loose all of it if you uninstall your spree gem and reinstall it. And you won't be able to deploy your changes to anywhere else as you are changing your local gem installation for customisation. Hope that helps